# How to make an image fit into a MUI grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, image, material-ui

I'm building an app with a collection of cards.
I am using React and MUI v5.

I use a grid and I'm having a lot of trouble keeping the image within the size of the grid item. I've tried about every solution I could find, different containers for the image but nothing seems to do the trick.

I also tried object-fit, or putting the image and as a background image of my grid item.
I know this has to do with the parent element not having a fixed dimension.
Is there a way to keep it dynamic while using MUI Grid?

```
    <Grid container item xs={12} border={1} direction="column">
      <Grid item xs={2} border={1}>
        TITLE
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={5} border={1}>
        <img
          src="https://mui.com/static/images/cards/paella.jpg"
          style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3} border={1}>
        description
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={2} border={1}>
        footer
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

It looks fine when the display is smaller.
[small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szLAh.png)

But it looks like this when the display is bigger.
[big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTMgf.png)

Answer (score 0):

As i can see image is kind of thumbnail in size, you can add bigger image to get best result for desktop. or You can make the image width 100% in style. As will fill the entire column.

```
    <img
      src="https://mui.com/static/images/cards/paella.jpg"
      style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}
    />
```